# CATCH statement not firing in SQL script

Tags: sql, transactions, try-catch

I was looking for a way to create a "wrapper" around some SQL Script Statements that would be both Transactional (Commit / Rollback) and give some kind of error message to the screen for the user running the script.

From another question, I posted I found what looked to be a good solution...

I can do the Transaction within the TRY and if any errors occur it should kick over to the CATCH and allow me to message the user.

Today I had an INSERT fail and it did not kick over to the CATCH it simply gave me an error (*There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.*)

Can someone help me understand what is happening and why it does not trigger the CATCH?

Here is the full code...

```
USE master;

-- Hide Record Counts
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Wrap Everything in a TRY -If we get any error it will jump to CATCH and stop executing the script
BEGIN TRY;

-- Start TRANSACTION within the TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

print('');
print('========= Step XX ==> START');
Print('');
Print('(( Some Action XXXX ))');
print('');

Create table #TempTest (
field1 varchar(10) null,
field2 varchar(10) null,
field3 varchar(10) null);

-- I will try to insert only 2 of the 3 columns so that I can trigger an error
-- Why does this not kick over to the CATCH?
INSERT INTO #TempTest (field1, field2, field3)
VALUES ('value1','value2');


-- COMMIT Transaction - If we had encountered an error it would have jumped to the CATCH block
COMMIT;

print('');
print('========= Step XX ==> FINISHED');
Print('');

-- End the TRY wrapper
END TRY

-- Here is the CATCH if we have any errors in the TRY section this will execute
BEGIN CATCH
    -- We need to make sure something actually happened that can be ROLLBACK
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        print('');
        print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   Opps we ran into some kind of ERROR.   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<');
        print('');
    END;
END CATCH;

-- Reset the NOCOUNT to Off
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't trigger the catch because it's not getting to the point where it's even running any of your SQL. The compilation phase is, correctly, determining your SQL is invalid - specifically this part

```
INSERT INTO #TempTest (field1, field2, field3)
VALUES ('value1','value2');
```

If you update it to

```
INSERT INTO #TempTest (field1, field2)
VALUES ('value1','value2');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO #TempTest (field1, field2, field3)
VALUES ('value1','value2', 'value3');
```

It'll get past that compilation and actually try and run the SQL code. If during that it encounters an issue, say the insert fails because the primary key already exists, your catch statement will trigger.

If you need to be able to log out messages for compilation failures you could consider something like *sp_executesql*

```
begin try
  declare @Statement nvarchar(max) = N'I am bad syntax'
  exec sp_executesql @statement = @Statement
end try
begin catch
  print 'Here'
  print ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch
```

To execute multiple statements within sp_executesql you can generate a string that contains all requirement statements. You can use ; to separate them if you're generating it all in to a single line:

```
begin try
  declare @Statement nvarchar(max) = 'select 1;select 2;select 3'
  exec sp_executesql @statement = @Statement
end try
begin catch
  print 'Here'
  print ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch
```

The above will generate 3 different result sets

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me. I understand that I was not including the proper number of values to match columns (I did this on purpose for this example). In real example some table in the middle

Comment: -- of my script was edited (a column that is no longer needed was removed) and it caused the script to fail (obviously), but when it did not fail as expected (i.e. triggering the CATCH) I was surprised. I now know that there is a difference between a **compilation error** and I guess what might be considered a **run-time error**. I appreciate you help on this!

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer with something that you may want to consider (I didn't include it originally because I wanted to confirm it worked :))

Comment: So if I understand correctly... When you execute some script using **exec sp_executesql** method within a **TRY** it will kick-over to the **CATCH** for both _Compilation Errors_ and _Run-Time Errors_ vs how I'm doing it now where I only get _Run-Time Errors_?

Comment: Quick second follow-up... If I have say 150 lines of script that is 4+ different discreet steps can I do something like the following: _DECLARE @ SQLText NVARCHAR(8000); SET @ SQLText = N' **All my 4+ steps here**; exec sp_executesql @SQLText_ ?  I guess I'm asking if **exec sp_executesq** has to be a single action or can it include multiple actions?

Comment: You can do multiple - I'll update the answer to show how